# Usage of the and its omission

Tags: grammar, definite-article, zero-article

Are these sentences without **the** grammatical? Should I omit it or retain it?

1. I love ***the*** people who love me.
2. ***The*** People who love animals are very kind hearted.

Comment: Both are grammatical but the meaning changes. There are **many** other questions here regarding the usage and omission of the definite article.

Comment: Could you please explain the differences in meaning?